# Playstore : This app may not be optimised for your device

Tags: android, tablet

Issue: On playstore when I visit my app from tablet I get "This app may not be optimised for your device" warning.

I have gone through various **questions(DUPLICATE)** on stackoverflow for this issue but I have not found the solution yet. Hence raising a new question.

I have already gone through the tablet app quality guidelines.

Also have already raised query with google filled "Design for tablet" form [Link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/tabletq)

This is the response I receive from Google.

> Upon further review, we have determined that your application, does not meet the basic tablet app quality checklist to be considered designed for use on tablet devices as explained here: http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/quality/tablet.html
>   8. Target Android Versions Properly 
>   http://developer.android.com/distribute/essentials/quality/tablets.html#android-versions
>   9. Declare Hardware Feature Dependencies Properly 
>   http://developer.android.com/distribute/essentials/quality/tablets.html#hardware-requirements

As per the suggestions I have updated the manifest file and to test I have published them as Alpha build on the playstore but still I am getting the same not optimised warning on alpha build.

This is how the merged manifest looks like

```
    <manifest
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:versionCode="8010008"
android:versionName="8.1.0.8"
```

>

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.front"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x20000"
    android:required="true" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.location.network"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.microphone"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.screen.landscape"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.wifi"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="com.google.android.finsky.permission.BIND_GET_INSTALL_REFERRER_SERVICE" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<permission
    android:name=".permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="0x2" />

<uses-permission
    android:name=".permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Gradle file below :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

    buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
            maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'
        }
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 26
        buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
        compileOptions.encoding = 'windows-1251'//
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "removed"
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode removed
            versionName "removed"
            multiDexEnabled true

            buildTypes.each {
                it.buildConfigField 'String', 'removed', removed
            }
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled true
                shrinkResources true
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
        implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
        implementation('com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0') {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        }
        implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.4@aar') {
            transitive = true
        }
        implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.4'
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.1'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
        implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.0.1'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0'
        implementation 'com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview:library:5.4.3'
        implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.28.0'
        implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.4'
        implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.4'
        implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.2'
        implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:1.6.0'
        implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
        implementation project(':app-release')
        implementation project(':SecureComponent-release')
        implementation files('libs/secure-component-sdk.jar')
        implementation files('libs/achartengine-1.1.0.jar')
        implementation files('libs/jackson-annotations-2.1.1.jar')
        implementation files('libs/jackson-core-2.1.1.jar')
        implementation files('libs/jackson-databind-2.1.1.jar')
        implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
        annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
        implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.0'
        implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp:1.5.0'
        implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.4.0'
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife'
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Also have checked for the optimization tips on google console but there are no tips recommended.

Please help!

Comment: Well, did you follow Google's instructions?  Are you targeting the correct minimum SDK versions?  Did you make sure that your app supports various types of tablet hardware?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, in the manifest also it is visible. min is 16 and target is 23.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use below in **AndroidManifiest.xml** file outside **application** tag. By default not all the screen sizes are supported, you need to manually allow them by registering in Manifiest file.

```
 <supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

Comment: I believe these tags are required if the app's minsdk is less than 13. But mine min is 16. But still I will give it a try on a alpha build.

Comment: No, these are just to support all the screen sizes. In your case TAB is not supported

Comment: I added the support screens but that did not help. I have checked this on Samsung Tab SM-T561. Still getting the same warning.

Comment: what is the **targetSdkVersion**? make sure it matches your device

Comment: Also try to submit at least one 7-inch and one 10-inch screenshot on Google PlayStore.

Comment: TargetSkdVersion is 23 and I have already submitted more than 1 screenshot for 7 and 10 inch tablet.

Comment: can you post **build.gradle** file in the question?

Comment: I have added the gradle file. Thank you

Comment: why is **versionCode** showing as removed. You need to put this in the gradle file

Comment: @Rahul Khurana I have removed it because of company policies. I don't think version code and name are related to app not optimised error.

Comment: In the official [docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning) they prefer to put the versionCode in the build.gradle. I guess this would be the cause of not optimised error